# SimplePing Apple Delegates not firing

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

Following issue:

I implemeted a Ping Object:

```
@interface PingTest : NSObject <SimplePingDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) SimplePing* ping;
```

SimplePing i got from Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SimplePing/Introduction/Intro.html

Now i am trying to send a Ping like this:

```
@synthesize ping;

ping = [SimplePing simplePingWithHostName:PING_SERVER];
ping.delegate = self;
[ping start];

#pragma mark - SimplePingDelegates

- (void)simplePing:(SimplePing *)pinger didStartWithAddress:(NSData *)address {
}

- (void)simplePing:(SimplePing *)pinger didSendPacket:(NSData *)packet
{
NSLog(@"didSendPacket");
}

- (void)simplePing:(SimplePing *)pinger didFailToSendPacket:(NSData *)packet error:(NSError *)error
{
NSLog(@"didFailToSendPacket");
}

- (void)simplePing:(SimplePing *)pinger didReceivePingResponsePacket:(NSData *)packet
{
NSLog(@"didReceivePingResponsePacket");
}
```

But my delegate methods are not called...Anyone knows why?!

EDIT: For some reason inside SimplePing.m:

```
- (void)start
// See comment in header.
{
// If the user supplied us with an address, just start pinging that.  Otherwise
// start a host resolution.

if (self->_hostAddress != nil) {
    [self startWithHostAddress];
} else {
    Boolean             success;
    CFHostClientContext context = {0, (__bridge void *)(self), NULL, NULL, NULL};
    CFStreamError       streamError;

    assert(self->_host == NULL);

    self->_host = CFHostCreateWithName(NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef) self.hostName);
    assert(self->_host != NULL);

    CFHostSetClient(self->_host, HostResolveCallback, &context);

    CFHostScheduleWithRunLoop(self->_host, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);

    NSLog(@">CFHostStartInfoResolution");
    success = CFHostStartInfoResolution(self->_host, kCFHostAddresses, &streamError);
    NSLog(@"<CFHostStartInfoResolution");
    if ( ! success ) {
        [self didFailWithHostStreamError:streamError];
    }
}
}
```

the "HostResolveCallback" never gets called....Thats the problem i think...

Comment: HostAddress are basic structures for all syscalls and functions that deal with internet addresse. If you supplied a IP address then this method will never be executed. Try using a well known address such as Google Open Dns 8.8.8.8. and also check if didStartWithAddress methods being called..

Comment: I don´t supply an IP Address...[SimplePing simplePingWithHostName:PING_SERVER]; The PING_SERVER is "www.google.com"...didStartWithAddress won´t be called as well....

Comment: If i take the old version from Apple, without ARC, it works...

Comment: Same problem here, but I cannot find the older version nor the latest working

Comment: Found the problem. see answer

Answer (score 1):

ARC is deallocating the `SimplePing` instance (`*ping` in your case) instead of using property use an iVar like this
Also you forget to add `sendPingWithData` to `didStartWithAddress` delegate method. Lookat

```
@implementation PingTest
{
    /*CHANGED*/
    SimplePing *_pinger;
}

- (void) startPinger
{
    /*CHANGED*/
    ping = [SimplePing simplePingWithHostName:PING_SERVER];
    ping.delegate = self;
    [ping start];
}


#pragma mark - SimplePingDelegates

- (void)simplePing:(SimplePing *)pinger didStartWithAddress:(NSData *)address 
{
    /*CHANGED*/
    [pinger sendPingWithData:nil];
}

- (void)simplePing:(SimplePing *)pinger didSendPacket:(NSData *)packet
{
    NSLog(@"didSendPacket");
    /*CHANGED*/
    //Capture time here if you want to measure the latency
}

- (void)simplePing:(SimplePing *)pinger didFailToSendPacket:(NSData *)packet error:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"didFailToSendPacket");
}

- (void)simplePing:(SimplePing *)pinger didReceivePingResponsePacket:(NSData *)packet
{
    NSLog(@"didReceivePingResponsePacket");

    /*CHANGED*/
    //Capturing time here again and comparing it with the one from didSentPacket will 
    // give you the latency
}
```