# Swift SimplePing doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, latency

I'm using SimplePing to get the latency in my swift application but I don't get any result.

This is the code taken form an example here in SO:

```
import Foundation

public typealias SimplePingClientCallback = (String?)->()

public class SimplePingClient: NSObject {
    static let singletonPC = SimplePingClient()

    private var resultCallback: SimplePingClientCallback?
    private var pingClinet: SimplePing?
    private var dateReference: NSDate?

    public static func pingHostname(hostname: String, andResultCallback callback: SimplePingClientCallback?) {
        singletonPC.pingHostname(hostname, andResultCallback: callback)
    }

    public func pingHostname(hostname: String, andResultCallback callback: SimplePingClientCallback?) {
        resultCallback = callback
        pingClinet = SimplePing(hostName: hostname)
        pingClinet?.delegate = self
        pingClinet?.start()
    }
}

extension SimplePingClient: SimplePingDelegate {
    public func simplePing(pinger: SimplePing, didStartWithAddress address: NSData) {
        pinger.sendPingWithData(nil)
    }

    public func simplePing(pinger: SimplePing, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
        resultCallback?(nil)
    }

    public func simplePing(pinger: SimplePing!, didSendPacket packet: NSData!) {
        dateReference = NSDate()
    }

    public func simplePing(pinger: SimplePing!, didFailToSendPacket packet: NSData!, error: NSError!) {
        pinger.stop()
        resultCallback?(nil)
    }

    public func simplePing(pinger: SimplePing, didReceiveUnexpectedPacket packet: NSData) {
        pinger.stop()
        resultCallback?(nil)
    }

    public func simplePing(pinger: SimplePing!, didReceivePingResponsePacket packet: NSData!) {
        pinger.stop()

        guard let dateReference = dateReference else { return }

        //timeIntervalSinceDate returns seconds, so we convert to milis
        let latency = NSDate().timeIntervalSinceDate(dateReference) * 1000

        resultCallback?(String(format: "%.f", latency))
    }
}
```

And to call the SimplePing in my viewController I do that:

```
let simplePingClient = SimplePingClient()
        simplePingClient.pingHostname("www.apple.com") { latency in
        print("Your latency is \(latency ?? "unknown")")
        self.labelTempsReponse?.text = latency
        }
```

When I put a breakpoint at this line:

```
simplePingClient.pingHostname("www.apple.com") { latency in
```

all the results are nil (the resultCallBack, the pingClient and the dateReference). I made a research to solve this issue and I found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22766499/simpleping-apple-delegates-not-firing) similar to mine but in objective c.

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 3):

The signatures in `SimplePingClient` don't match the `SimplePingDelegate` protocol it is trying to implement.  Perhaps these once matched in some earlier version, but as of Swift 5/XCode 12.2 and using [Apple's SimplePing code](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/SimplePing/Introduction/Intro.html) last updated 2016 they don't.  Some datatypes are wrong, some parameter labels mismatched, and some parameters missing.  This means `SimplePingClient` never gets its callbacks because `SimplePing` looks for a matching signature in the delegate object, finds none, and skips the callback.

Further, because `SimplePing.h` declares these delegate methods as **optional** you get no compiler errors.

To see the errors, and to get XCode to offer to write protocol stubs for you, comment out the @optional in the `SimplePingDelegate` definition in `SimplePing.h` (line 142).

Here are the changes to the `SimplePingClient` class extension I needed to make to get SimplePingClient to work:

```
extension SimplePingClient: SimplePingDelegate {
    
    public func simplePing(_ pinger: SimplePing, didStartWithAddress address: Data) {
        pinger.send(with: nil)
    }

    public func simplePing(_ pinger: SimplePing, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        resultCallback?(nil)
    }

    public func simplePing(_ pinger: SimplePing, didSendPacket packet: Data, sequenceNumber:UInt16) {
        dateReference = Date()
    }

    public func simplePing(_ pinger: SimplePing, didFailToSendPacket packet: Data, sequenceNumber: UInt16, error: Error) {
        pinger.stop()
        resultCallback?(nil)
    }

    public func simplePing(_ pinger: SimplePing, didReceiveUnexpectedPacket packet: Data) {
        pinger.stop()
        resultCallback?(nil)
    }

    public func simplePing(_ pinger: SimplePing, didReceivePingResponsePacket packet: Data, sequenceNumber:UInt16) {
        pinger.stop()

        guard let dateReference = dateReference else { return }

        //timeIntervalSinceDate returns seconds, so we convert to milis
        let latency = Date().timeIntervalSince(dateReference ) * 1000

        resultCallback?(String(format: "%.f", latency))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

could it be the case that simplePingClient is going out of scope ? In this case, the simplePing will shutdown. 
Try to declare as a global variable:

```
var simplePingClient : SimplePingClient!
```

and then this should work:

```
simplePingClient = SimplePingClient()
    simplePingClient.pingHostname("www.apple.com") { latency in
    print("Your latency is \(latency ?? "unknown")")
    self.labelTempsReponse?.text = latency
    }
```